# Implementing C#'s using in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, typescript, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

I have many functions like that:

```
async function getUser(username: string) {
    var db = await connect();

    try {
        var result: User[] = await db.collection("users").find({"username": username}).toArray();
        return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : null;
    }
    finally {
        await db.close();
    }
}
```

and `connect()` function looks like that:

```
async function connect(): Promise<Db> {
    return await MongoClient.connect("connection string");
}
```

I want to avoid using the `try/finally`, `connect()` and `close()` in every function. I would like to have a magic, like the `using` statement is C#:

```
async function getUser(username: string) {
    using(var db = new MongoClient()) {
        var result: User[] = await db.collection("users").find({"username": username}).toArray();
        return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : null;
    }
}
```

How can I eliminate this code duplication?

Notice that I can use any TypeScript or ECMAScript6+ solution as well as any new feature that I need to install in order to use.

Although, a simple JavaScript solution using DI or any other design pattern would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of a solution just as I finished typing my question. I decided to share it anyway, just in case someone would find it useful.

```
async function useMongoDB<T>(func: (db: Db) => Promise<T>) {
    var db = await connect();

    try {
        return await func(db);
    }
    finally {
        await db.close();
    }
}

export async function getUser(username: string): Promise<User> {
    return await useMongoDB(async (db: Db) => {
        var result: User[] = await db.collection("users").find({"username": username}).toArray();
        return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : null;
    });
}
```

Comment: @NKijak I can't. It says that I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.